# paramiko's ssh channel closed after executing one cmd - Python

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I'm using `Python`'s `Paramiko` to execute commands in a remove server. The code is much simple.

Here's my definition of the `SSHConn` class:

```
class SSHConn:

  def __init__(self, hostname, user, pwd, filename=None):
    self.client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    self.client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    self.client.connect(hostname, username=user, password=pwd,
                          key_filename=filename)
    self.transport = self.client.get_transport()
    self.channel = self.transport.open_session()
```

So I'm running the following code:

```
local_ssh = ssh.SSHConn(host, user, passwd)

cmds = ('foo', 'bar')
for cmd in cmds:
   local_ssh.channel.exec_command(cmd)
   self.log.info(local_ssh.channel.recv(1024))
```

However, when I execute the following code snipped I'm getting:

```
INFO:paramiko.transport:Connected (version 2.0, client OpenSSH_6.6.1p1)
INFO:paramiko.transport:Authentication (publickey) failed.
INFO:paramiko.transport:Authentication (password) successful!
INFO:paramiko.transport:Secsh channel 1 opened.
INFO:testsets.testcase:
ERROR:testsets.testcase:Channel is not open
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/fds-src/source/test/integration-framework/testsets/testcases/test_100gb_volume.py", line 87, in runTest
    local_ssh.channel.exec_command(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/channel.py", line 209, in exec_command
    raise SSHException('Channel is not open')
SSHException: Channel is not open
ERROR:testsets.testcase:Test Case Test100GBVolume failed.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/fds-src/source/test/integration-framework/testsets/testcases/test_100gb_volume.py", line 87, in runTest
    local_ssh.channel.exec_command(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/channel.py", line 209, in exec_command
    raise SSHException('Channel is not open')
SSHException: Channel is not open
```

How can I keep the channel open?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `channel` docs are very clear about this point. You need to open a new channel for each `exec_command`.

> exec_command(*args, **kwds)
>
> Execute a command on the server. If the server allows it, the channel will then be directly connected to the stdin, stdout, and stderr of the command being executed.
>
> When the command finishes executing, the channel will be closed and can’t be reused. You must open a new channel if you wish to execute another command.

The `SSHClient` object has an `exec_command` method that does this for you.